# JBD2 has a Fork Bomb? Kill -9 Wont Work (Ubuntu 12.04)

Tags: 12.04, kill

This process is writing to my disk at 10MB/sec and I cant kill it. I think its a bug/fork bomb in Ubuntu 12.04.

See:

```
root@beb:~# ps -efaww|grep jbd2
root       355     2  0 Jun23 ?        00:31:13 [jbd2/sda5-8]
root      1458     2  0 Jun23 ?        00:00:13 [jbd2/sda6-8]
root      8963     2  0 Jun23 ?        00:00:02 [jbd2/dm-3-8]
root     23457 23053  0 10:13 pts/13   00:00:00 grep --color=auto jbd2
root@beb:~# kill -9 355 1458 8963
root@beb:~# ps -efaww|grep jbd2
root       355     2  0 Jun23 ?        00:31:13 [jbd2/sda5-8]
root      1458     2  0 Jun23 ?        00:00:13 [jbd2/sda6-8]
root      8963     2  0 Jun23 ?        00:00:02 [jbd2/dm-3-8]
root     23457 23054  0 10:13 pts/13   00:00:00 grep --color=auto jbd2

root@beb:/proc# lsof|grep jb
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfs-fuse-daemon file system /home/lmadmin/.gvfs
  Output information may be incomplete.
jbd2/sda5   355       root  cwd       DIR                8,5         4096          2 /
jbd2/sda5   355       root  rtd       DIR                8,5         4096          2 /
jbd2/sda5   355       root  txt   unknown                                                /proc/355/exe
jbd2/sda6  1458       root  cwd       DIR                8,5         4096          2 /
jbd2/sda6  1458       root  rtd       DIR                8,5         4096          2 /
jbd2/sda6  1458       root  txt   unknown                                                /proc/1458/exe


$sudo iotop
Total DISK READ:       0.00 B/s | Total DISK WRITE:    1966.97 K/s
TID  PRIO  USER     DISK READ  DISK WRITE  SWAPIN     IO>    COMMAND                 
355 be/3 root        0.00 B/s   22.96 MB/s  0.00 % 93.93 % [jbd2/sda5-8]
```

How do I stop jbd2? THank you so much

Comment: That's a kernel process, and is certainly not a fork bomb. You can't (shouldn't) kill it. 10KB/s shouldn't slow down the drive much.

Comment: Sorry, Typo its MB/sec. Its still running, and there is no way to stop this without a reboot?